# .htaccess Rewrite Rule for (s)html File, Get Parameter lost

Tags: html, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting, get

since a few hours I'm trying to create a rewrite rule, where instead of a php file
a rewrite to an shtml file should be the result.
The filename is rewritten, but I always lose the get parameter (Is not passed to the shtml file when called).
If I do the same with a php file it works.

Does not work:
 `RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ LookAt.shtml?q=$1 [L,NC]`

Does work:
 `RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ LookAt.php?q=$1 [L,NC]`

I already tried QSA etc. somehow nothing works (Google returns many results for .php,
for .(s)html I didn't find anything useful),
I hope someone can give me a tip, I'm already going crazy with this problem....
Thanks!

Comment: And you have verified that calling `.../LookAt.shtml?q=something` directly works as expected to begin with, yes?

Comment: Yes, with a direct call I can see the parameters (I output all parameters via a console.log), With rewrite a 'empty string' is logged.

Comment: The rules you have shown would not explain why the parameter would not get passed to `LookAt.shtml`. I'm guessing that it _does_ get passed - but that your actual SSI statements don't get interpreted any more (should be verifiable, by looking at the HTML source code the browser receives) - because the rewrite module, and the module parsing those, are probably not doing their work in the correct order here.

Comment: "I output all parameters via a console.log" - how exactly are you reading the URL parameters in `LookAt.shtml`?

Comment: I use : console.log(window.location.search); (To debug the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use : `console.log(window.location.search);` (To debug the issue)

That's the problem. You can't use *client-side* JavaScript to read the query string from a URL that is rewritten *server-side*. Given a request for `/search/foo` there is no query string on the client-side request.

Client-side JavaScript only sees the requested URL in the browser. For example:

```
// Outputs "https://example.com/search/foo"
console.log(location.href);
```

The same applies to the `.php` file. But you were perhaps checking `$_GET['q']` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead in the server-side script?

Since you were using `.shtml` I assumed you would be using Server-Side-Includes (SSI) to access the query string. For example:

```
// Outputs "q=foo"
console.log('<!--#echo var="QUERY_STRING" -->');
```

If you are only using client-side JS then you'd probably just parse the requested URL directly in order to extract the search phrase. eg. `/search/foo`. (No need to rewrite the request to append a query string in this case. Simply rewriting to `LookAt.shtml` would be sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution!
I decided to implement it via the SSI, then both the direct and rewrite call work: 
`var queryString = '<!--#echo var="QUERY_STRING" -->';`
`console.log("QueryString : "+queryString);`